# pi deprecated on OS X 10.8

Tags: objective-c, c, osx-mountain-lion, pi

Is there a replacement for `pi` const on OS X 10.8?

When I use it I get the following warning:

```
'pi' is deprecated: first deprecated on Mac OS X 10.8
```

It works but I want to get rid of that warning.

Comment: This is **not related to Xcode.** Retagged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try including `math.h`, which defines the C standard library macro `M_PI`.

Comment: H2CO3 and Jean Nicolas suggeted right track for deprication of pi.I had tried in my own Project as per their suggestions :)